# The spring cloud gateway does not respond after multiple visits to the Actuator interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

The spring cloud gateway does not respond after multiple visits to the Actuator interface. In the actuator access path, I set up a webfilter to authenticate to token using the restTemplate access authentication service. After accessing the actuator multiple times, all requests fail to respond, and other services that use Tomcat do not.

The following versions have been tried, and the same problem will occur
Operating environment: Windows10 22H2, Intellij IDEA 2022.3, JDK1.8 8u341 Oracle HotSpot
SpringBoot version: 2.3.12.RELEASE, 2.6.3
Gateway version: 2.2.9.RELEASE, 3.1.1
Registration Center: Nacos 2.1.1
Cloud version: Hoxton. SR12, 3.1.1
CloudAlibaba version: 2.2.7.RELEASE, 2021.0.1.0

It would be better if you could answer in Chinese!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, the versions listed are no longer supported, please update to the latest and try again